# Buy map in Beijing

Tags: china, maps, beijing, xian

Need to buy laminated good quality maps of China, Beijing and Xian. I need maps in English. Would you recommend any shops in Beijing and Xian?

Comment: I have a foldable paper map of Beijing but it's kind of big if you open it. I guess your best shot to collect one is at hotels or tourist centers, although I doubt it will be laminated. Alternative: take pictures of a map with your phone or download an offline map or such.

Answer (score 3):

Quite near the Forbidden City is the Foreign Language Bookshop, which I always visit when in Beijing. I am pretty sure they sell maps, absolutely sure they sell a very wide range of English source material, and don't know whether they do laminated maps. Do bear in mind that maps of China may be restricted in various ways -availability; production in English; restrictions on who they can be sold to. I am not aware of anything similar in Xian.

Answer (score 1):

In Beijing the [Wangfujing Bookstore](http://www.thebeijinger.com/directory/wangfujing-bookstore) sells a wide variety of maps. In 2012 this was on the ground floor, directly to your left after you enter the store.

Answer (score 0):

In beijing I would recommend to go to the public library which is right in the center of the town.

They have everything in any language you might think!